# different vim rules for different filetypes

Tags: javascript, css, ruby, vim

I want CSS / SCSS / JS files to have different rules. This question feels like something super common however I wasn't able to find anything!

I tried this from what I found, it didn't work

```
autocmd *.css, *.scss, *.js set shiftwidth=2
autocmd *.css, *.scss, *.js set softtabstop=2

autocmd *.rb set shiftwidth=4
autocmd *.rb set softtabstop=4
```

The error is

```
E215: Illegal character after *: *.css, *.scss, *.js set shiftwidth=2
```

Comment: Why is this a Ruby, JavaScript or CSS question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You left off the name of the autocommand event(s).  Try

```
:autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.css,*.scss,*.js set shiftwidth=2  softtabstop=2
:autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.rb set shiftwidth=4  softtabstop=4
```

Alternatively (especially if you use more file types and/or more than a few options) use filetype plugins.  Start with

```
:filetype plugin on
```

and see whether you like the settings provided by the default ftplugins.  Well, I just checked, and neither CSS nor javascript nor ruby set the `'shiftwidth'` options for you.  So read

```
:help ftplugins
:help ftplugin-overrule
```

for how to add your own settings.

Comment: An alternative to `autocmd`'s and fullblown ftplugins is the `after/ftplugin` folder. See `:h after-directory`. I would imagine that is a good place for setting such as these.

Comment: @PeterRincker:  The `after/ftplugin` directory is described as one of the options under `:help ftplugin-overrule`, and this section of the help gives more context.  Either way, this relies on adding `:filetype plugin on` to the user's vimrc file.